# django rest swagger is pulling the comments, as seen in raw. Clicking: show/hide, list operations, expand operations show nowthing

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger

django-rest-swagger is pulling the comments from view class and its  methods: list, retrieve etc, as seen in click raw> JSON.

 However, Clicking: show/hide, list operations, expand operations show nothing.

Note: I am using **viewsets.ViewSet**

This means it is being able to extract the docstring but not publish them.

I am using:

- Python 2.6.6
- django 1.5.2
- djangorestframework 2.4.8
- yaml 3.11
- rest_framework_swagger 0.3.4
- markdown 2.4.1
- django-filter 0.11.0
- six 1.10.0

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    """ Some Operations



        HTTP_200_OK will be send after a successful operation

        Post --> create

        Get --> list  !!

        Put --> update 

        Patch --> partial update




    """
```

This works for me.
Django 1.8, rest framework 3.1.2